# Remove single pixel from image

Tags: python, gdal

I need to remove single pixel from (binary) raster image of 8-bit. I have used GDAL Python to generate the binary image. How to run 3 by 3 window without losing continuous pixels and remove single pixels? Focal maximum option in ERDAS has been used for testing required image and its working. Equivalent image calculation with Python and GDAL to be required.

Comment: Manually? From vector data?

Comment: By removing a pixel, do you mean to update its value into nodata, or perhaps to update into some value that is related to the neighboring pixels? Is this your homework or something else?

Comment: yes.i want to make zero for single pixels.and remaining cluster can remain same.more than one pixel can remian.only raster image. no vector.

Comment: Try https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_sieve.html?